# 502 Bad Gateway in elasticbeanstalk of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a spring boot application in elasticbeanstalk.
In the "application.properties" file, I have set,

server.port=5000

I have added a RDS db and set the following environment properties.

[image]

I have also added an inbound rule in the security group of the environment as shown in the image below:

[image]

I am still getting the 502 Bad Gateway error when I click on the URL.

Comment: you click the URL of the Elastic Beanstalk? does it have :5000 at the end? eg. https://somewebsite.com:5000

Comment: No. Here is the link:  http://porhaxali-env.eba-mir937ev.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

Comment: how does elastic beanstalk know that it needs to go to port 5000 if you don't put it in the URL? by default URL for HTTP is using port 80

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is incorrect.

`0.0.0.0/32` means that you accept traffic only from the IP address `0.0.0.0` which basically doesn't exist.

What you want to do is allow traffic from `0.0.0.0/0` which means accept traffic from anywhere in the world.

Comment: I changed to 0.0.0.0/0 but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Elastic Beanstalk, in your instance there is an nginx reverse proxy, which accepts HTTP connections on port `80` and proxies these connections to port `5000`.

In your security group inbound rule you should accept `HTTP` connections on port `80` from everywhere (`0.0.0.0/0`).